# Getting Spaces not a space as output in c++ program

Tags: c++, string

In a c++ program how to get an output like the following one:

```
*   *
```

Basically, for example how to get three spaces between these two asterisks as an output?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say "how do I get a variable amount of spaces" instead?

Comment: Sir actually I am a beginner and i was just introduced to c++ three days ago.

Comment: @NikosC. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Almost any C++ book will teach you how to do this within the first few chapters. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388284

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "*   *"; }
```

Comment: Ask a silly question, get a silly answer!